# Issues with Parse Cloud Code Promises

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform, promise, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to work with Parse Cloud Code and use promises to make sure I eliminate any issues with cals being async. I am wanting to query a class, get an object back, build up some JSON, then query some relations of the object (tags, referees) and add them to the JSON to return back for ExpressJS to render. The code I paste is not working but I don't understand why if each time I am returning to project for the next promise to query on.

**Edit:**

```
//Return a single project
Parse.Cloud.define('getProject', function(request, response) {
    var projectUrl = request.params.projectUrl;

    var project;
    var projectsData = [];

    var Projects = new Parse.Object("projects");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Projects);
    query.equalTo("projectUrl", projectUrl);
    query.find().then(function(projectsResult) {
        console.log(projectsResult.length + " Projects returned");

        project = projectsResult[0];
        var projectData = {
            "id": project.get("id"),
            "title": project.get("title"),
            "previewImage": project.get("previewImage"),
            "longDescription": project.get("longDescription"),
            "shortDescription": project.get("shortDescription"),
            "visibleToPublic": project.get("visibleToPublic"),
            "dateStart": project.get("dateStart"),
            "dateEnd": project.get("dateEnd"),
            updatedAt: project.get("updatedAt"),
            projectStatus: project.get("projectStatus")
        };

        projectsData.push(projectData);
        console.log("Step 1. Projects Data: " + JSON.stringify(projectsData));

        var tagsQuery = project.relation('tags');
        return tagsQuery.query().find();
    }).then(function(tags) {
        var tagsData = [];
        for(var t = 0; t < tags.length; t++) {
            var tagData = {
                "tag": tags[t].get("tag"),
            }
            console.log("Tag Data: " + tagData);
            tagsData.push(tagData);
        }
        projectsData[tags] = tagsData;
        console.log("Step 2. Tags Data: " + JSON.stringify(tagsData));

        var refereesQuery = project.relation('referees');
        return refereesQuery.query().find();
    }).then(function(referees) {
        var refereesData = [];
        for(var r = 0; r < referees.length; r++) {
            var refereeData = {
                "name": referees[r].get("name"),
                "role": referees[r].get("role"),
                "emailAddress": referees[r].get("emailAddress"),
                "phoneNumber": referees[r].get("phoneNumber"),
                "linkedInUrl": referees[r].get("linkedInUrl"),
            }
            console.log("Referee Data: " + refereeData);
            refereesData.push(refereeData);
        }
        projectsData[referees] = refereesData;
        console.log("Step 3. Referees Data: " + JSON.stringify(refereesData));

        console.log("Everthing should be part of Projects Data here: " + JSON.stringify(projectsData));

        response.success(projectsData);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error("Error: " + error);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues :

- Confusion between `projectsData` and `projectData`
- `projectsData` isn't actually necessary.
- `projectData` needs to be in scope in the three places it is (or should be) used after it is created & assigned.
- In several cases `.then()` is used where standard synchronous flow will suffice. Purging the unnecessary .thens will help greatly in sorting out the scope issues.

Doing little more than shuffling the code around, I arrive at the following :

```
Parse.Cloud.define('getProject', function(request, response) {
    var Projects = Parse.Object.extend("projects"); // with credit to @kRiZ
    var query = new Parse.Query(Projects);
    query.equalTo('projectUrl', request.params.projectUrl);
    query.find().then(function(projectsResult) {
        var project = projectsResult[0];
        var projectData = {
            'id': project.get('id'),
            'title': project.get('title'),
            'previewImage': project.get('previewImage'),
            'longDescription': project.get('longDescription'),
            'shortDescription': project.get('shortDescription'),
            'visibleToPublic': project.get('visibleToPublic'),
            'dateStart': project.get('dateStart'),
            'dateEnd': project.get('dateEnd'),
            'updatedAt': project.get('updatedAt'),
            'projectStatus': project.get('projectStatus')
        };

        //Now make the tags query and the referees query in parallel.
        var tagsPromise = project.relation('tags').query().find();
        var refereesPromise = project.relation('referees').query().find();

        // Aggregate the two promises with Parse.Promise.when(), and handle the responses.
        return Parse.Promise.when(tagsPromise, refereesPromise).then(function(tags, referees) {
            //Process the tags response
            projectData.tags = tags.map(function(t) {
                return {
                    'tag': t.get('tag')
                };
            });
            //Process the referees response
            projectData.referees = referees.map(function(r) {
                return {
                    'name': r.get('name'),
                    'role': r.get('role'),
                    'emailAddress': r.get('emailAddress'),
                    'phoneNumber': r.get('phoneNumber'),
                    'linkedInUrl': r.get('linkedInUrl')
                };
            });
            // Yay!
            response.success(projectData);
        });
    }).fail(function(error) {
        response.error('Error: ' + error);
    });
});
```

Apart from the overall rearrangement, the only substantial changes are :

- Using `Array#map()` to map an array to another array.
- Making two queries in parallel and using `Parse.Promise.when()` to aggregate the two promises.

Comment: This worked fantasitcally @Roamer-1888. Now I just have to work out how to query a different class and add to my buildup of data/

Comment: Mark, if the third query is dependent only on `promise`, then my pattern should extend nicely to accommodate it. Just add another `var xxxxPromise = project.relation...` statement, add `xxxxPromise` to `Parse.Promise.when(...)`, and handle the response in the same/similar way to `tags` and `referees`.

Comment: So I think I followed your advice but was not getting the population I was hoping for. I also tried chaining the promise to query deeper i.e.

But that didn't work either. 
I have updated my code on the follow up question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34146245/returning-deeper-relations-in-parse-cloud-code-when-using-promises

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with your initial query. You are trying to use subclasses, but your syntax is wrong.

Your query should begin like this:

```
var Projects = Parse.Object.extend("projects");
var query = new Parse.Query(Projects);
```

**EDIT:**

Also, you are returning objects, you should return promises.
See code below (not tested):

```
Parse.Cloud.define('getProject', function(request, response) {
    var projectUrl = request.params.projectUrl;
    var projectsData = [];

    var Projects = Parse.Object.extend("projects");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Projects);
    query.equalTo("projectUrl", projectUrl);
    query.find().then(function(projectsResult) {
        console.log(projectsResult.length + " Projects returned");

        var project = projectsResult[0];
        var projectData = {
            "id": project.get("id"),
            "title": project.get("title"),
            "previewImage": project.get("previewImage"),
            "longDescription": project.get("longDescription"),
            "shortDescription": project.get("shortDescription"),
            "visibleToPublic": project.get("visibleToPublic"),
            "dateStart": project.get("dateStart"),
            "dateEnd": project.get("dateEnd"),
            updatedAt: project.get("updatedAt"),
            projectStatus: project.get("projectStatus")
        };

        projectsData.push(projectData);
        console.log("Step 1. Projects Data: " + JSON.stringify(projectsData));

        // Removed the return from here

        var tagsData = [];
        console.log("Project Step 2: " + JSON.stringify(project));
        var tagsQuery = project.relation('tags');
        return tagsQuery.query().find();
    }).then(function(tags) {
        for(var t = 0; t < tags.length; t++) {
            var tagData = {
                "tag": tags[t].get("tag"),
            }
            tagsData.push(tagData);
        }
        projectsData.tags = tagsData;
        console.log("Step 2. Tags Data: " + JSON.stringify(tagsData));

        // Removed return from here

        var refereesData = [];
        var refereesQuery = project.relation('referees');
        return refereesQuery.find();
    }).then(function(referees) {
        for(var r = 0; r < referees.length; r++) {
            var refereeData = {
                "name": referees[r].get("name"),
                "role": referees[r].get("role"),
                "emailAddress": referees[r].get("emailAddress"),
                "phoneNumber": referees[r].get("phoneNumber"),
                "linkedInUrl": referees[r].get("linkedInUrl"),
            }
            refereesData.push(refereeData);
        }
        projectData.referees =refereesData;
        console.log("Step 3. Referees Data: " + JSON.stringify(refereesData));

        response.success(projectsData);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error("Error: " + error);
    });
});
```

See Parse documentation [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#objects-retrieving-objects) on retrieving data using subclasses.

Comment: It's EXTREMELY frustrating when all the recent news about Parse Cloud Code is them talking about using Promises yet all the documentation is using callback. It's a mixed message and makes it hard to find useful examples. I changed the code above but still doesn't work. Error I get is:
`
Result: TypeError: Cannot call method 'relation' of undefined
`

Comment: Yeah, their documentation is not updated. The error is good, it means your promises are working. The error means that your object is null (undefined).

Comment: See update above. You were returning actual objects, should return promises. The code is untested though, but should give a general idea.

Comment: So after a few edits I have got the following working with all the console.logs printing what I would expect, but I can't check the last one that I would hope to have all complete JSON including the tags and the referees I am trying to add, so I am not sure it is working. From what the API Console is showing me it doesn't seem the case as it only appears to return the data from the first promise.

Comment: Thank you for you help @kRiZ I learnt a bit about promises from your responses, I appreciate it.