# Returning deeper relations in Parse Cloud Code when using promises

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, relationship, parse-cloud-code

I have received some excellent information on Parse promises so far and am ready to soak up the next bit of the puzzle to me... relations of relations. The following code is in most part in answering [Issues with Parse Cloud Code Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34124443/issues-with-parse-cloud-code-promises/34124815) but I have in the comments of the sections piece of code my next question. How would I go about further querying of relations within the top level relations? would be great to see how you would extend you code to do that @roamer-1888

**Latest:**

```
//Return a single project
Parse.Cloud.define('getProjectByUrl', function(request, response) {
    var Projects = Parse.Object.extend("projects"); // with credit to @kRiZ
    var query = new Parse.Query(Projects);
    query.equalTo('projectUrl', request.params.projectUrl);
    query.include("projectStatus"); // *MJ Added the include to add the project Status pointer
    query.find().then(function(projectsResult) {
        var project = projectsResult[0];
        //From here, `project` is hierarchically monkey-patched with the results of further queries.

        //Make tags query, the referees query and the sections query in parallel.
        var tagsPromise = project.relation('tags').query().find();
        var refereesPromise = project.relation('referees').query().find();
        var sectionsPromise = project.relation('sections').query().include("sectionType").find(); //*MJ Added the include of the sectionType pointer

        // Aggregate the three promises with Parse.Promise.when(), and handle the responses.
        return Parse.Promise.when(tagsPromise, refereesPromise, sectionsPromise).then(function(tags, referees, sections) {
            project.set('tags', tags);
            project.set('referees', referees);
            project.set('sections', sections);

            //Go deeper into `sections`
            var sectionsRelationsPromises = sections.map(function(section) {
                // *MJ Remove sectionTypesPromise as it's a pointer
                var filesPromise = section.relation('files').query().include("fileType").find(); // *MJ Added the include to grab the fileType pointer
                return Parse.Promise.when(filesPromise).then(function(files) {
                    //*MJ Removed the promise for section Types
                    section.set('files', files);
                    // *MJ Removed the Deeper Logic
                });
            });
            return Parse.Promise.when(sectionsRelationsPromises);
        }).then(function() {
            return project;
        });
    }).then(function(project) {
        // At this point, all the data is gathered in the form of Parse objects in project,
        // which now needs to be mapped into a js plain object.
        var projectData = projectObj(project);
        projectData.tags = project.get('tags').map(tagObj); //Process the tags response
        projectData.referees = project.get('referees').map(refereeObj); // *MJ removed one e from refereeObj //Process the referees response
        projectData.sections = project.get('sections').map(sectionObj); //Process the sections response
        // *MJ Removed the adding of the files and looking over the sections.

        //Yay! (hopfully)
        response.success(projectData);
    }).fail(function(error) {
        response.error('Error: ' + error);
    });

    // ***********************************
    // ***** start: mapper functions *****
    // ***********************************
    function projectObj(project) {
        return { // *MJ Removed the stray equals sign here
            'id': project.id,
            'title': project.get('title'),
            'previewImage': project.get('previewImage'),
            'longDescription': project.get('longDescription'),
            'shortDescription': project.get('shortDescription'),
            'visibleToPublic': project.get('visibleToPublic'),
            'dateStart': project.get('dateStart'),
            'dateEnd': project.get('dateEnd'),
            'updatedAt': project.get('updatedAt'),
            "projectStatus": project.get("projectStatus").get("status") //*MJ Added the get of the Project Status status.
        }
    }
    function tagObj(tag) {
        return {
            'tag': tag.get('tag')
        };
    }
    function refereeObj(referee) {
        return {
            'name': referee.get('name'),
            'role': referee.get('role'),
            'emailAddress': referee.get('emailAddress'),
            'phoneNumber': referee.get('phoneNumber'),
            'linkedInUrl': referee.get('linkedInUrl')
        };
    }
    function sectionObj(section) {
        return {
            'type': section.get('sectionType').get("type"), // *MJ Added the pointer for SectionType > type
            'order': section.get('order'),
            'content': section.get('content'),
            'files': section.get('files').map(fileObj)
        };
    }
    function fileObj(file) {
        return {
            'name': file.get('name'), // *MJ chnaged the name to be more appropriate
            'url': file.get('url'), // *MJ Added the missing comma
            'type': file.get('fileType').get("type") //*MJ Added the pointer for fileType > type and removed semi colon
        };
    }
    // *********************************
    // ***** fin: mapper functions *****
    // *********************************
});
```

**Old:**

```
//Return a single project
Parse.Cloud.define('getProject', function(request, response) {
    var Projects = Parse.Object.extend("projects"); // with credit to @kRiZ
    var query = new Parse.Query(Projects);
    query.equalTo('projectUrl', request.params.projectUrl);
    query.find().then(function(projectsResult) {
        var project = projectsResult[0];
        var projectData = {
            'id': project.id,
            'title': project.get('title'),
            'previewImage': project.get('previewImage'),
            'longDescription': project.get('longDescription'),
            'shortDescription': project.get('shortDescription'),
            'visibleToPublic': project.get('visibleToPublic'),
            'dateStart': project.get('dateStart'),
            'dateEnd': project.get('dateEnd'),
            'updatedAt': project.get('updatedAt')
        };

        //Now make the tags query and the referees query in parallel.
        var tagsPromise = project.relation('tags').query().find();
        var refereesPromise = project.relation('referees').query().find();
        var sectionsPromise = project.relation('sections').query().find();
        var sectionTypesPromise = project.relation('sections').query().find().relation('type').query().find();
        var filesPromise = project.relation('sections').query().find().relation('files').query().find();
        var fileTypesPromise = project.relation('sections').query().find().relation('files').query().find().relation('type').query().find();


        // Aggregate the two promises with Parse.Promise.when(), and handle the responses.
        return Parse.Promise.when(tagsPromise, refereesPromise, sectionsPromise, sectionTypesPromise, filesPromise, fileTypesPromise).then(function(tags, referees, sections, sectionTypes, files, fileTypes) {
            //Process the tags response
            projectData.tags = tags.map(function(tag) {
                return {
                    'tag': tag.get('tag')
                };
            });
            //Process the referees response
            projectData.referees = referees.map(function(refereee) {
                return {
                    'name': refereee.get('name'),
                    'role': refereee.get('role'),
                    'emailAddress': refereee.get('emailAddress'),
                    'phoneNumber': refereee.get('phoneNumber'),
                    'linkedInUrl': refereee.get('linkedInUrl')
                };
            });

            //Process the sections response
            projectData.sections = sections.map(function(section) {
                return {
                    'order': section.get('order'),
                    'content': section.get('content')
                };
            });

            // Problem: Sections have a relations column (files)
            // which I would like to return as a child of sections.
            // The files class then has a pointer column (type)
            // to another class which contains the a list of
            // file types (i.e. Image, Document, etc...)
            // The sections structure of projectDate should
            // look like:
            //
            // "sections": [{
            //   "type": "Section Type"
            //   "order": "1",
            //   "content": "This is the Section content",
            //   "files": [{
            //     "filename": "Image 1",
            //     "url": "image-1.png"
            //     "type": "Image"
            //   },
            //   {
            //     "filename": "Image 2",
            //     "url": "image-2.png",
            //     "type": "Image"
            //   },
            //   {
            //     ...
            //   }]
            //  },
            //  {
            //    ...
            //  }
            // }]

            //Process the section type response. This is reliant on sections being retrieved.
            projectData.sections.type = sections.map(function(sectionTypes) {
                return {
                    'type': sectionTypes.get('type')
                };
            });

            //Process the section files response. This is reliant on sections being retrieved.
            projectData.sections.files = sections.map(function(files) {
                return {
                    'filename': files.get('filename'),
                    'url': files.get('url')
                };
            });

            //Process the section files types response. This is reliant on files being retrieved.
            projectData.sections.files.type = sections.map(function(fileTypes) {
                return {
                    'type': fileTypes.get('type')
                };
            });
            // Currently not so Yay!

            response.success(projectData);
        });
    }).fail(function(error) {
        response.error('Error: ' + error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow, I must have unlocked the "Attract douchebags who don't understand people learn in different ways" level. You don't know what I have and haven't tried. Maybe if the Parse documentation was clearer it would be easier for me, but it's not and from the answers I have seen it doesn't really appear clear to others what the right way is to do something. Your profile doesn't even show any Parse tags so it sounds like you best staying out of the topic anyway seen as you have nothing to add. Other people here are helpful and willing to share the knowledge they have.

Comment: Hero Status unlocked!!! Hahahaha. Go away and let the people willing to help others consume my bandwidth. It's funny how you have deleted and edited your comments though.

Comment: "Currently not so Yay!" made me giggle. Working on it.

Comment: Hey if I can't laugh about bad skills, I'll end up sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going deeper than one level is slightly more complicated. Each level needs a pattern much like the top level pattern.

Unfortunately, these patterns don't naturally lend themselves to being "flat". The need to constantly refer back to earlier results makes nesting attractive, though probably not absolutely necessary; I'm sure that other approaches exist.

Here's an attempt at the code. With no means of testing it, there may well be mistakes.

```
//Return a single project
Parse.Cloud.define('getProject', function(request, response) {
    var Projects = Parse.Object.extend("projects"); // with credit to @kRiZ
    var query = new Parse.Query(Projects);
    query.equalTo('projectUrl', request.params.projectUrl);
    query.find().then(function(projectsResult) {
        var project = projectsResult[0];
        //From here, `project` is hierarchically monkey-patched with the results of further queries.

        //Make tags query, the referees query and the sections query in parallel.
        var tagsPromise = project.relation('tags').query().find();
        var refereesPromise = project.relation('referees').query().find();
        var sectionsPromise = project.relation('sections').query().find();

        // Aggregate the three promises with Parse.Promise.when(), and handle the responses.
        return Parse.Promise.when(tagsPromise, refereesPromise, sectionsPromise).then(function(tags, referees, sections) {
            project.set('tags', tags);
            project.set('referees', referees);
            project.set('sections', sections);

            //Go deeper into `sections`
            var sectionsRelationsPromises = sections.map(function(section) {
                var sectionTypesPromise = section.relation('type').query().find();
                var filesPromise = section.relation('files').query().find();
                return Parse.Promise.when(sectionTypesPromise, filesPromise).then(function(sectionTypes, files) {
                    section.set('type', sectionTypes[0]);
                    section.set('files', files);
                    //And deeper still into each of the section's files to find their types
                    var filesRelationsPromises = files.map(function(file) {
                        return file.relation('type').query().find().then(function(fileTypes) {
                            file.set('type', fileTypes[0]);
                        });
                    });
                    return Parse.Promise.when(filesRelationsPromises);
                });
            });
            return Parse.Promise.when(sectionsRelationsPromises);
        }).then(function() {
            return project;
        });
    }).then(function(project) {
        // At this point, all the data is gathered in the form of Parse objects in project,
        // which now needs to be mapped into a js plain object.
        var projectData = projectObj(project);
        projectData.tags = project.get('tags').map(tagObj); //Process the tags response
        projectData.referees = project.get('referees').map(refereeeObj); //Process the referees response
        projectData.sections = project.get('sections', sections).map(sectionObj); //Process the sections response
        projectData.sections.each(function(section) {
            section.files = section.get('files').map(fileObj);
        });
        //Yay! (hopfully)
        response.success(projectData);
    }).fail(function(error) {
        response.error('Error: ' + error);
    });

    // ***********************************
    // ***** start: mapper functions *****
    // ***********************************
    function projectObj(project) {
        return = {
            'id': project.id,
            'title': project.get('title'),
            'previewImage': project.get('previewImage'),
            'longDescription': project.get('longDescription'),
            'shortDescription': project.get('shortDescription'),
            'visibleToPublic': project.get('visibleToPublic'),
            'dateStart': project.get('dateStart'),
            'dateEnd': project.get('dateEnd'),
            'updatedAt': project.get('updatedAt')
        }
    }
    function tagObj(tag) {
        return {
            'tag': tag.get('tag')
        };
    }
    function refereeObj(referee) {
        return {
            'name': referee.get('name'),
            'role': referee.get('role'),
            'emailAddress': referee.get('emailAddress'),
            'phoneNumber': referee.get('phoneNumber'),
            'linkedInUrl': referee.get('linkedInUrl')
        };
    }
    function sectionObj(section) {
        return {
            'type': section.get('type'),
            'order': section.get('order'),
            'content': section.get('content'),
            'files': section.get('files').map(fileObj)
        };
    }
    function fileObj(file) {
        return {
            'filename': file.get('filename'),
            'url': file.get('url')
            'type': file.get('type');
        };
    }
    // *********************************
    // ***** fin: mapper functions *****
    // *********************************
});
```

I've made the code as simple as possible to follow by :

- limiting the first .then's callback to gathering data asynchronously.
- orchestrating the mapping of the gathered data in a subsequent .then's callback.
- pulling out the individual mapper functions into a separate section at the end.

Trust me, that is more readable than doing everything in a single block. I tried that, and it was nightmarish.

Happy debugging.

Comment: Hey @roamer-1888
I have cleaned the code up a bit and tried a few different attempts at finishing it off, but the problem appears in:

       projectData.sections = project.get('sections', sections).map(sectionObj); //Process the sections response
        projectData.sections.each(function(section) {
            section.files = section.get('files').map(fileObj);
        });
        //Yay! (hopefully)
I removed the second sections from project.get('sections', sections) because it said it wasn't defined. I changed each to forEach but then error is  Object #<Object> has no method 'get'\n

Comment: Mark, I'm not surprised that part was buggy. I was cross-eyed by that point. I think it's actually made simpler by calling the files mapper within the sections mapper. I've made a few edits above, including one for `section.type` which was also wrong.

Comment: Hey there @Roamer-1888, thank for the edits. I have put back in the OP as **Latest** my edits that I documented , I think it's simplifying down even further and is now returing the JSON I had hoped for. Check it out and see if I have done anything glaringly stupid and any other feedback you feel like giving.

Comment: Mark, do I understand correctly that it's working? It certainly looks like it should. Everything looks totally reasonable, especially my corrected syntax errors :-) I had looked at `.include()` in the documentation and wondered if it might work - way better than what I suggested. Just one thing to improve - the `sections.map(...)` now does just one query at the next level, therefore `Parse.Promise.when()` is not necessary - you can run the promise chain straight through, `return section.relation('files').query().include("fileType").find().then(...);`

Comment: What I posted above worked. I'm just tied up a little today, but I'll try those suggested edits and then I'll post it all up. You've certainly helped me in a massive way to better understand promises. I would not say my understanding is complete yet but it's in a better position than before your help.

Answer (score 0):

To treat the question generally: say you have an class called "ClassA" and it has a relation called "classBs" relating it to many instances of "ClassB".  And say, also, that "ClassB" instances have a relation called "classCs" relating them to instances of "ClassC".

```
ClassA --relates to many --< ClassB --relates to many --< ClassC
           ("classBs")                 ("classCs")
```

Now, given a single instance of "ClassA", how would one go about fetching all of the "ClassC" instances related to it via "ClassB"?

The answer is straight-forward, remembering a few things: (1) spell out the data model very clearly as done here, (2) compose more complex logic out of smaller, simpler promise-returning primitives (3) use Parse.Promise.or to execute the union of multiple queries.

```
var _ = require("underscore");

// return a promise for many instances of ClassC related to the given aObject
function getCsFromA(aObject) {
    var bRelation = aObject.get("classBs");
    return bRelation.query().find().then(function(bObjects) {
        // gather all of the bObject's relation's queries
        var  queries = _.map(bObjects, function(bObject) {
            return aObject.get("classCs").query();
        });
        // get the union of many queries
        return Parse.Query.or(queries);
    });
}
```

A couple practical points: queries are by default limited to 100, and you can change the limit up to 1000.  At maximum, a thousand relations of a thousand relations is a million results.  This will certainly violate some resource constraints at parse.com.